# converting a vb.net code snippet to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Visual Studio 2005.

I was converting some of my source code to C#.

However, when I was doing the code snippet below, I noticed I don't have the IsNumber method.

Why is the IsNumber missing? I wanted to use it so that I can force a user to enter only numbers.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) = False Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the static `char.IsNumber()`:

```
char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar);
```

By the way, I think you want to use `char.IsDigit()` instead. This comes from the MSDN site:

> `IsNumber()` determines if a Char is of any numeric Unicode category. This contrasts with `IsDigit()`, which determines if a Char is a radix-10 digit.

In other words, `IsNumber()` also returns true for non-western numbers like 六 (Chinese '6').

Comment: Thanks, you got there just before me.

Answer (score 3):

C# is more strict in allowing you to call shared members on an instance variable.

Your original code gives me a warning in VB.

> Warning   1   Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

In C# - it's just not allowed.  Your solution to use `char.IsNumber` is the way to go; and that code will work the same in either language.

```
public class Example1
{
    public static int Test() { return 0; }

    public Example1()
    {
        this.Test();  // This doesn't work
        Example1.Test();  // This does
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Used the following:

```
    if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) == false)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

we normally use [developer fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to convert code from vb.net to c# and vice-versa.
you can also try it.